# Bit-bang I2C implement on DS1307 and Atmega328P problem

Tags: avr, i2c, rtc, bit-bang

I currently implement I2C bit-bang for Master Arduino (AVR) to Read/Write to Arduino Slave using Wire.h and DS1307 RTC. My bit-bang i2c work perfectly with Arduino Slave read 8 bytes without corruption and blink led if the data is right.

Now I implement on DS1307, Although I can write 0x00 to DS1307 Successful after sending ADDR+Read bit the DS1307 return NAK (My bit-bang I2C Release SDA pin after sending so the Slave can pull down without open-drain/collector gpio). I have no clue why I can't read from Ds1307 since it works perfectly with Arduino Slave sending 8 bit and I also follow the procedure of Ds1307 communication.

**Master(i2c bitbang) read from Arduino Slave(Wire.h) 8 bytes data**

[image: 1]

**Using Library to read DS1307**

[image: 2]

**My Bit-bang i2c try to read from DS1307**

[image: 3]

````
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// CODE from STM32
#define SDA PB0
#define SCL PB1
//OUTPUT REGISTER: PORTB
// PB0: Pin A4 - SDA | PB1: Pin A5 - SCL | Arduino (Atmega328P)
#define SDA_ON (PORTB |= (1 << PB0))
#define SDA_OFF (PORTB &= ~(1 << PB0))
#define SCL_ON (PORTB |= (1 << PB1)) // PORTB = 0b0000 0010
#define SCL_OFF (PORTB &= ~(1 << PB1))

#define READ_SDA() (PINB & (1 << SDA))
#define READ_SCL() (PINB & (1 << SCL))

#define SET_SDA_OUT() DDRB |= (1 << SDA)
#define SET_SDA_IN() DDRB &= ~(1 << SDA)

#define PB2_ON (PORTB |= (1 << PB2))
#define PB2_OFF (PORTB &= ~(1 << PB2))

#define I2C_READ 0x01
#define I2C_WRITE 0x00

#define ADDR 0x68 //Slave Address
#define ADDR_W (ADDR << 1)
#define ADDR_R (ADDR_W | 1)

void init()
{
    DDRB = (1 << DDB0) | (1 << DDB1) | (1 << DDB2);
    SCL_ON;
    SDA_ON;
}

void start()
{
    SDA_ON;
    _delay_us(4.5);
    SCL_ON;
    _delay_us(4.5);
    SDA_OFF;
    _delay_us(4.5);
    SCL_OFF;
    _delay_us(4.5);
}

/*  i2c stop sequence */
void stop()
{
    SDA_OFF;
    _delay_us(4.5);
    SCL_ON;
    _delay_us(4.5);
    SDA_ON;
    _delay_us(4.5);
}

/* Transmit 8 bit data to slave */
uint8_t Tx(uint8_t dat)
{

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if (dat & 0x80)
        {
            SDA_ON;
        }
        else
        {
            SDA_OFF;
        }
        _delay_us(3);
        SCL_ON;
        _delay_us(5);
        SCL_OFF;
        _delay_us(2);
        dat <<= 1;
    }
    SET_SDA_IN();
    _delay_us(3);
    SCL_ON; // the 9th pulse is high
    _delay_us(5);
    if (READ_SDA())
    {
        _delay_us(3);
        SCL_OFF; // the 9th pulse is low
        PORTB = 0x00;
        SET_SDA_OUT();
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        _delay_us(3);
        SCL_OFF; // the 9th pulse is low
        PORTB = 0x00;
        SET_SDA_OUT();
        return 1;
    }
}

uint8_t Rx(bool ack)
{
    uint8_t byte = 0;
    uint8_t bit = 0;

    _delay_us(10);
    SET_SDA_IN();
    _delay_us(5);

    for (bit = 0; bit < 8; bit++)
    {
        byte <<= 1;
        do
        {
            SCL_ON;
        } while (READ_SCL() == 0);
        _delay_us(3);
        if (READ_SDA())
        {
            byte |= 0x01;
        }
        _delay_us(2);
        SCL_OFF;
        _delay_us(5);
    }

    PORTB = 0b00000001;
    SET_SDA_OUT();
    ack ? SDA_ON : SDA_OFF;
    SCL_ON;
    _delay_us(7);
    SCL_OFF;
    _delay_us(1);
    return byte;
}

int main(void)
{
    //uint8_t data1;
    unsigned char ack;
    
    init();
    _delay_ms(3000);
    
    while (1)
    {
        start();
        ack = Tx(ADDR_W);
        if (!ack)
        {
            stop();
            break;
        }
        Tx(0x00);
        stop();

        _delay_us(1);

        start();
        ack = Tx(ADDR_R);
        if (!ack)
        {
            stop();
            break;
        }
        _delay_us(30);
        Rx(0);  //1
        Rx(0);  //2
        Rx(0);  //3
        Rx(0);  //4
        Rx(0);  //5
        Rx(0);  //6
        Rx(1);  //7
        stop();

        PB2_ON;
        _delay_ms(1000);
    }
}
```
````

Comment: You can compare your code with this library: https://github.com/bitbank2/BitBang_I2C It appears to have been tested with the DS1307

Comment: I still think the problem is that you insist on having push-pull outputs and did not fix the code to open-drain. You can't have two outputs driving same wire to different directions without problems.

Comment: Yes, I know the problem with push-pull, after Tx(Addr+Read-bit) I have release the SDA line for the slave and slave set NAK, not the master. I already simulate the DS1308 with Arduino, Slave send back ACK then send 8 bytes

Comment: do not use push/pull anywhere in the code. We've given suggestions on how to fix it.

Comment: @MinhTem But you don't understand that when you write the read address, your MCU keeps the SDA pushed high until you change it to input, while the DS1308 already starts to pull SDA low to signal the ACK before you change it to input. That why you must never ever push high, it is wrong, and that can be the reason why your code does not work.

Comment: Oh thank @Justme so much, Now I realize but What should I do when GPIO on Atmega328P does not support open-drain. Should I modify my code that only sets SDA output when need, all the time must be input?

Comment: @MinhTem But it does support open-drain. It can be set to output high, output low, input with pull-up or input without pullup under software control. You are doing the bit-banging in sofware, so you can bit-bang it in any way you like to implement open-drain.

Comment: I have modified start(), stop(), Tx() to SET_SDA_OUT at the beginning so when they must pull the SDA low or high for initialize or transmit. SET_SDA_IN at the end of them to release SDA line but result not change :( DS1307 still send NAK although I have release SDA all the time. Is it right to read DS1307 we must begin with Write the pointer register 0x00 then begin Read ... I also has 2 pull-up resistor 4.7K connect with 5v on SDA and SCL line.

Comment: Umm, when *reading* bytes, it's the master that must send the ACK bit. Or NAK if it wants the slave to stop.

Comment: @Janka That is what the receive code does - but that is not part of the problem, as the code does not even go to the receiving code part. The writing of I2C address with read bit fails even before that, as the slave chip fails to ACK it.

Comment: @Justme right, I have tried to free the SDA line all the time but the result still there, Success Write slave addr+write bit an 0x00 ( pointer of DS1307 seconds register ), then Write slave addr+ read bit and Rx() for request read from slave but somehow slave fail to ACK it. After 2 hours, I have success full receive data from slave ( Arduino use Wire.h) and send to another slave (ESP8266 also using Wire.h)

Comment: I try free SDA line by only SET_SDA_OUT() when master need to create start condition, stop condition, send data then SET_SDA_IN() all the time. @Justme what do you think about other possibilities?  I  followed to procedure from here: https://exploreembedded.com/wiki/Real_Time_Clock(DS1307)_with_AVR

Comment: I will update my current code with the full notes. Please keep in touch with me ^^~

Comment: I think you should read Atmel's application note how to make a bit-banging I2C master. They explained in great detail how to do it properly, and the document has been around for about 20 years now, so it should be easy to find.

Comment: @MinhTem i am facing the same problem while trying to read data with attiny4. Do you find the solution. If yes then please help me. Awaiting for your reply